# Como embarcar em uma gem um arquivo de configuração?

Tags: ruby, gem

Criei uma Gem que funciona muito bem até ela ser chamada de fora do working dir. Preciso embarcar um arquivo de configuração de modo que seja possível chamar o executável de qualquer lugar. Não me é interessante colocar em `/etc/`, já que a gem ficará instalada pelo usuário.

Estrutura da gem já instalada:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── exe
│   └── fluffy
├── fluffy.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── fluffy
│   │   ├── gui.rb
│   │   ├── sqlfluff.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── fluffy.rb
└── sqlfluff.cfg
```

Nele eu faço uma chamada de shell que preciso indicar o caminho de `sqlfluff.cfg`, porém não sei como fazer isso. O caminho de instalação dessa gem na minha máquina está em `~/.asdf/installs`, mas não posso garantir que este seja sempre o caminho de instalação.

Atualmente, rodando no diretório raiz da Gem funciona, o código que puxo o `sqlfluff.cfg` e uso para invocar outro programa CLI:

```rb
def fix_format(sql)
    dialect = "postgres"
    config_file = "sqlfluff.cfg"
    v = `sqlfluff fix --dialect #{dialect} --config #{config_file} - <<< \"#{sql}\"`
    return v
end
```